# Using a local variable inside a filter on a remote powershell session

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I searched quite a time for this issue and found serveral links with using variables on remote power shell sessions:

[Using a local variable in a remote powershell session](https://4sysops.com/archives/using-a-local-variable-in-a-remote-powershell-session/)

[Passing local variables to a remote session in PowerShell 3.0](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/01/23/pstip-passing-local-variables-to-a-remote-session-in-powershell-3-0/)

But I could not find a solution to the part how to pass it into a quoted filter formula...

Here is what I thought should work:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $hex_session {New-AddressList -Name ($args[0] + " - All Rooms") -RecipientFilter ("(CustomAttribute1 -eq '" + $args[0] + "' -and (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'ConferenceRoomMailbox')") -RecipientContainer ("bla.blup.com/Hosted/"+$args[0])} -ArgumentList $Tenant
```

But did not...

The original command on which I enter on the server is:

```
New-AddressList -Name "Tenant00001 – All Rooms" -RecipientFilter "(CustomAttribute1 -eq 'Tenant00001') -and (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'ConferenceRoomMailbox')" -RecipientContainer "bla.blup.com/Hosted/Tenant00001"
```

Any one had the same issue?

Thanks for your help

Cheers
Yves

Answer (score 1):

Okay... with some more trial and error. I was able to solve it myself.

Here is the solution:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $hex_session {New-AddressList -Name ($args[0] + " - All Rooms") -RecipientFilter ("(CustomAttribute1 -eq '$args') -and (RecipientDisplayType -eq 'ConferenceRoomMailbox')") -RecipientContainer ("bli.blup.com/Hosted/"+$args[0])} -ArgumentList $Tenant
```